# CKEditor setData not clearing or changing text in rte

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, ckeditor, backbone-views

I have an instance of CKEditor inside a Backbone View with a plugin that posts whatever text is in the editor to my site on click. I want to clear the CKEditor on click as well but using setData doesn't work. It flashes as though *something* is happening, but then resets to the same data that was already there.

It's called inside the plugin like this:

**note**: `THIS` is a variable referencing the Backbone View

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'post', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand('post', {
            exec: function(editor) {
                THIS.model.postMessageAttempt(editor.getData());
                THIS.options.data = "";
                editor.setData("");
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('Post', {
            label: THIS.i18n.postText(),
            command: 'post'
        });

    }
} );
```

I've also tried with `setData("some text")` and `THIS.editor.setData("")` (I have a reference to the editor saved in the View) but both had the same result. Any ideas about what is going wrong?

**EDIT**
I've also tried using CKEditor's integration with jQuery with this call `THIS.$el.find('textarea' + this.id).val("");` and it doesn't flash anymore, but it still doesn't clear out the editor.

Comment: So everything works except that `setData(...)` isn't doing anything, right?

Comment: And does it work if you `setData('<p></p>')`?

Comment: Correct. And that doesn't work either.

Comment: So `getData` works, `setData` doesn't, and both `editor` variables reference the same thing. Have you tried this outside of Backbone? I'm wondering if CK and Backbone are fighting each other for control of a DOM element.

Comment: I have not. I _can_ use `insertHtml` though, so if they are, it's only in this very specific case.

Comment: Is there some sort of "refresh" method that you need to call to sync everything after a `setData` call? Sorry, I haven't done any work with CKEditor in awhile and I remember it being it rather frustrating experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was twofold: First, `setData` calls a function, `afterSetData`, at the end of the function and that function calls `getData`. `getData` calls the function `beforeGetData` at the beginning of the function and *that* function calls `setData`. I think the goal was to get around the fact that there's a lot of shallow referencing instead of deep referencing but even in the un-minified `ckeditor.js` it was unclear why this was done.

And Second, that *I* was also calling `disableEnablePost`, in order to correctly enable/disable posting from the editor to the site, on many events (focus, key[down], etc). `disableEnablePost` called `getData` which caused timing issues with my call to `setData` in the `post` plugin.

**Problem:**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'post', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand('post', {
            exec: function(editor) {
                THIS.model.postMessage(editor.getData());
                THIS.options.data = "";
                editor.setData("");
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('Post', {
            label: THIS.i18n.postText(),
            command: 'post'
        });
        editor.on('key', function (event) {
            THIS.disableEnablePost(editor.getCommand( 'post' ), event);
        });
    }
} );
```

Here is my **solution**:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'post', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand('post', {
            exec: function(editor) {
                THIS.model.postMessage(editor.getData());
            }
        });
       ...
    }
} );
```

`model.postMessage` now triggers an event when it has completed which is caught in the view and then calls this function:

```
clearRTE: function() {
    this.editor.setData("");
    this.options.data = "";
}
```

Finally, I changed `disableEnablePost` so that it doesn't call `getData` every time, which was not a good practice. Now, it calls `editor.getSnapshot()` which is much more lightweight, there's no data processing, and no calls to either `getData` or `setData` so it's better for the frequent use.